# Correlation Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

I am using the laucher-csharp demo project of Docusign and it works well when I am debugging in VS2019. However, when I try to run it on the staging server we keep getting the error: /Home/Error?`message=Correlation%20failed.` after the authentication but before getting into the documento to sign.

We tried many different settings and inside and outside the server.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there's an issue (tracked on the DocuSign side under issue number DEVDOCS-3071) with how Chrome disallows insecure cookies. If you try again using Firefox or Edge, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: If this is the Chrome issue, then using your app via https will also solve the problem. (And https is always preferred.)

Answer (score 0):

[Correlation failed in net.core / asp.net identity / openid connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262561/correlation-failed-in-net-core-asp-net-identity-openid-connect) This may help give some context.
Suggest you check other browsers and Chrome cookie settings.
Also, if you need to authenticate from your staging server, you will need to update the URL of that server in the OAuth by going to [API and Keys page](https://admindemo.docusign.com/authenticate?goTo=apiIntegratorKey) and finding your key and adding it.