# Correlation failed error in .NET Core on Chrome default SameSite settings when using on http://localhost with OAuth

Tags: c#, google-chrome, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, samesite

The requirements are:

1. Use http://localhost and then redirect to complete OAuth process and redirect back.
2. Use Chrome with default settings. I know I can just change some flags to fix this.
3. Use the .NET Core library for Auth Code Grant. I also know I can write my own code for this.

You can see all our code in [this repo](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp) and here is a [direct link to startup.cs](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/Startup.cs).

The cookie related code in there is this:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

I tried to either remove the above code or change it in different ways - no go.
I also read [this article](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/) and tried to use the code that was offered in there - didn't work.
I also tried all of the different solutions offered on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262561/correlation-failed-in-net-core-asp-net-identity-openid-connect). Again, nothing seemed to work.
Is there any option to still use http and samesite cookies with Chrome and prevent .NET Core from giving me this error?

Answer (score 0):

Could you capture and post the Authorization Code Grant request and response details? It is not clear whether or not your problem is related to SSL.

**ASIDE: REAL WORLD OAUTH DEVELOPER SETUP**

When working with OAuth tech, I always run with real world URLs on a developer PC:

- https://web.mycompany.com
- https://api.mycompany.com

This results in fewest technical / trust issues - I never use URLs such as http://localhost:3000.

It is not too difficult and this approach may resolve your issues - if it helps here are a few resources:

- [Host File Setup](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/15/developer-domain-setup/)
- [Developer SSL Configuration](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/11/developer-ssl-setup/)
- [Fiddler .Net Core Setup](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp)
- [Scripts to Create Certificates via OpenSSL](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/tree/master/api/certs)

Comment: Gary, thank you but this is an absolute requirement of this one - we must use localhost. I wrote this very early in the question.
This is not a real world project, it's an educational project to help beginner developers. So your answer didn't really help, but I still appreciate it.