# Auth0 - Blazor - Login response cookie not set to Secure

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, auth0

I am building a simple Blazor Server-side App. I followed the steps mentioned in the [blog](https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-blazor-tutorial-on-building-webapp-with-authentication/) to setup Auth0 authentication.
Things work fine as long as I am on localhost in debug mode.

The moment I published the app to the local IIS server, I started getting error the moment I clicked on the login button. On checking the windows event viewer, I noticed that the cookie sent by login was discarded and that threw an exception.

[image: Event Viewer Warning]

Before this, I can see a warning that says that the cookie has set **SameSite=None** and so it must set ‘**Secure**’.

[image: Event Viewer Warning]

I have since then tried multiple changes in the Program.cs to handle this but none of the settings worked.

**Things that I have tried -**

1. Adding the following setting -

   ```
    builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;});
   ```
2. Adding a custom class to handle this situation as suggested in the blog - [Thinktecture](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identityserver/prepare-your-identityserver/)
   Both these work fine in localhost debug mode but give same error as above when deployed to local IIS.

And I have **not enabled https** redirect.

Any help to sort this out is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me -

1. Enabled Https binding on IIS -
   [IIS - Https Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD6GN.png)
2. Enabling https redirection in Program.cs
3. Adding https port in appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

I follow the blog you provided and I also find this issue. I [have try a lot of method to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262561/correlation-failed-in-net-core-asp-net-identity-openid-connect), but failed.

And I find sentence. `Please note: The setting SameSite=None will only work if the cookie is also marked as Secure and requires a HTTPS connection.` So the first method will not work.

After deployed the project and I find it works in IE, but not in Chrome or Edge.
So I think it's not the code issue, [it related with Broswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63211514/7687666).

And the bad new is, we can't find Google Chrome 'SameSite by default cookies' and 'Cookies without SameSite must be secure' flags taken away after update v91.

**Workaround**

1. Use Https
2. Use IE

Comment: are those workarounds exclusive?  (Do you need all users to use IE in order to use Auth0?)

Comment: I have tried with IE and it dosent seem to work. Just to confirm, when you say Use Https, you mean to just insert app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in the Program.cs right? Do we need to install self-signed certificate after that?