# Why are .NET 6 Application + Application Gateway + Open ID Connect - Path based routing on different app services not working

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, openid-connect, .net-6.0, azure-application-gateway

I have an application gateway set up ("gateway"):
`apps.mydomain.com`

I have an app service set up ("app"):
`my-app-service.azurewebsites.net`

The path based rule is set on the listener for on the gateway address above.

`/apps/app1/*`

The default backend target and settings are set to the root of the gateway address above.

I am using AADS as the authentication store.

Both work correctly independently as I have another route set up on the gateway. I can go to the app service and it will prompt me for credentials, then take me to the index page at the root.

```
my-app-service.azurewebsites.net/
```

What I am trying to do is set up a path based rule that routes through the gateway and lands on a path under apps.mydomain.com.  For example,

```
apps.mydomain.com/apps/app1.
```

I have set up the gateway properly as I can get to a static page.  For example,

```
apps.mydomain.com/apps/app1/somedirectory/mystaticpage.html.
```

My problem is that when I try to authenticate, I think the signin-oidc is routing the request incorrectly.  I am able to authenticate, and it appears to pass back to apps.mydomain.com/apps/app1/signin-oidc and then the middleware passes back to the root.  It is authenticating, because when it hits the error page, it shows me as logged in.

I have tried overriding the cookie policy options:

```
builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
//options.HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.None;
});
```

I have tried listening to the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider:

```
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{

//options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/apps/app1/");
//options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/apps/app1/signin-oidc");
//options.CallbackPath = "/apps/app1/signin-oidc";
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
    {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262561/correlation-failed-in-net-core-asp-net-identity-openid-connect
        context.Options.NonceCookie.Path = "https://apps.mydomain.com/apps/app1/signin-oidc";
        context.Options.CorrelationCookie.Path = "https://apps.mydomain.com/apps/app1/signin-oidc";

        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-http-headers-protocol#front-door-to-backend
        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://apps.mydomain.com/apps/app1/signin-oidc";
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
};
});
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
// By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

My guess is that just setting the otions.CallbackPath should work, but I just get correlation or sorry, we cannot log you in errors when I try that.  Not sure if there is an error in the library.

I have spent over a month on and off and engaged MS technical support trying to solve this, but have not been able to get this to work.  I can't imagine I am the only one doing this.  I know it is in the open ID connect middleware somewhere, but cannot find the correct combination.

This is just a demo project in .NET 6 to get this working correctly.  Any code will do.  If there is actual working code somewhere that would be great.  Just need to get the path based routing with authentication to work.

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @ToreNestenius:  **HTTPS** all around.  The gateway listener listens for http and forwards to HTTPS as well..